# Evaluating the derivative of y=1/x

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

If you look closely in step 4,delta x is multiplied with 1/delta x in the first numerator and last denominator.
The rules of fractions are :
A/B/C=AC/B. Isn't this a discrepancy?

$y=\frac{1}{x}$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{d y}{d x}=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+\Delta x}-\frac{1}{x}}{\Delta x} \\
=\frac{d y}{d x}=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{x-(x+\Delta x)}{(x+\Delta x) x}}{\Delta x} \\
\frac{d y}{d x}=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-\Delta x}{\frac{(x+\Delta x) x}{\Delta x}}=-\frac{\Delta x \times \ 
{1/\Delta x}}{\frac{x^2+\Delta x \cdot x}{\Delta x \times \frac{1}{\Delta x}}} \\
=\frac{-1}{x^2+x \Delta x}=\frac{d y}{d x}=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-1}{x^2+x \Delta x} \\
=\frac{-1}{x^2+x \lim _{\Delta x} \Delta x}=\frac{-1}{x^2+0}=-\frac{1}{x^2} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: $(A/B)/C = A/BC$ and $A/(B/C)=AC/B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the working out is typed/formatted very badly. The step before is
$$ \lim_{x\to\Delta x} \frac{(\frac{-\Delta x}{(x+\Delta x)x})}{\Delta x} = \lim_{x\to\Delta x} \frac{-\Delta x}{x \Delta x (x+\Delta x)}$$ and should have been written either with brackets or as a single fraction. And from here it is clear that we can multiply top and bottom by $ \frac{1}{\Delta x} $ to get the result
$$ \lim_{x\to\Delta x}\frac{-\Delta x \times \frac{1}{\Delta x}}{x \Delta x (x+\Delta x) \times \frac{1}{\Delta x}} = \lim_{x\to\Delta x} \frac{-1}{x (x+\Delta x) } $$ and the result follows.

So you are right that $ \frac{A}{(\frac{B}{C})} = \frac{AC}{B} $ but we are looking at $ \frac{(\frac{A}{B})}{C} = \frac{A}{BC} $ but it is formatted in a way that it very difficult to read.

Comment: I want to clear one more confusion if you wouldn't mind? How do I know that in the step (that you referred to as "the step before") the parenthesis are on the first two fractions and not that last one? Since I don't see why can't we put the parenthesis on the last two

Comment: That grouping (which is correct) is literally from the definition of the derivative which has $f(x+h)-h$ as the numerator which is a difference of fractions that can be combined into one fraction **before** even considering dividing by $h$. So it is of the form (A/B)/C with no ambiguity.

Comment: @AtticusWaters as AlgTop1854 said they are around the top 2 because that is where they should be based of off the first couple of steps. What you should do is put brackets around the top of your fraction in the very first step, then keep them there throughout and see it it clears it up. If not, let me know and I can type up the full working in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Jacob! I've solved it the way you described it and now all confusions have gone away and I can solve the rest of the questions in the exercises as well. Thank you once more

Answer (score 1):

$A/B/C$ is ambiguous.  The following are true as long as not dividing by $0$:

$(A/B)/C= A/(BC)$

$A/(B/C) = AC/B$

and in the middle steps you've somehow mixed up this distinction and probably made two errors that wash out since you got the right answer.

A simpler approach (using $h$ instead of $\Delta x$ and omitting $\lim$ for simplicity of display) is:

$$\frac{\frac1{x+h}-\frac1{h}}{h}                 $$
$$\frac{\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h}                 $$
$${\frac{-h}{xh(x+h)}}              $$

[prior step used $(A/B)/C = A/(BC)$]

$${\frac{-1}{x(x+h)}}              $$

And finally let $h\rightarrow 0$.

A good rule of thumb is to clear complex fractions as simply and quickly as possible. The way I have laid it out, an alternative is to take step 1 and multiple the entire expression by $x+h$ over itself which clears it immediately.